# Dapper - pass whole entity as query parameter or anonymous object

Tags: c#, dapper

I want to know if there are any recommendations with query parameters

Is it ok to pass the whole object or is it better to create a lightweight anonymous object with properties I need?

```
Query<SomeObj>("Select * from SomeObjs where Id = @Id", someObj);
```

or

```
Query<SomeObj>("Select * from SomeObjs where Id = @Id", new {someObj.Id});
```

Are there any performance or memory implications for one over other?

Comment: The best way to find out is to test them, but I doubt you'll see any significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

For how Dapper works, by creating and caching the mapping code on the fly at the first use, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: So, if an object have 100 properties that wouldn't impact performance vs using anonymous object with single property?

Comment: Dapper will create the mapping code on-the fly the first time the query is executed, so Reflection will hit performance only one time. So, just by looking at source code, I would expect a really minimal (if at all) impact on performance, even because you are only passing Id, so no matter how many properties your object have, only one will me mapped. Of course properties needs to be scanned via reflection, but as said before it will happen only one time.

Comment: Aside performance implications that, as said, are practically absent, I would say that the most correct way, architecturally speaking, to pass parameter is using the second option which is basically another way to implement and use a DTO, or using Dynamic Parameters: that would make clear what you want to do and what values are really used. In addition to that you will have the ability to map properties to parameters that may have a different name.